# MapServer raster from PostGIS fails to load

Tags: raster, postgis, mapserver

I have a PostGIS with a raster stored in a table (`solardensity.density`).

I want to create a map service with MapServer like this:

```
LAYER
  NAME "raster"
  TYPE raster
  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:2056"
  END
  STATUS ON
  DATA "PG:host=postgis port=5432 dbname='geodata' user='www-data' password='pw' schema='solardensity' table='density' column=rast mode=2"      
  PROCESSING "NODATA=-99999"
  PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
  PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
  CLASSITEM "[pixel]"
  CLASS
    MINSCALEDENOM 15001
    STYLE
      COLORRANGE "#fff2cc" "#990000"
      DATARANGE 3 10
      OPACITY 89
    END
  END 
END
```

This fails even though I can display this table in QGIS. In the MapProxy log I can see this:
`Unable to access file. Corrupt, empty or missing file`.

When I load another raster table from the same schema, it renders correctly with MapServer. I cannot see the difference between the two rasters.

Also, I can force the MapProxy error when I choose a non-existing table in the MapServer data definition. However, my table exists and the error still appears.

The error from MapServer is as follows:

```
msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'raster'. msDrawRasterLayerLow(): Unable to access file.

Corrupt, empty or missing file 'PG:host=postgis port=5432 dbname='geodata' user='www-data' password='pw' schema='solardensity' table='density' column=rast mode=2' for layer 'raster'.

Error browsing database for PostGIS Raster properties : no connection to the server
```

Any idea what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Your question made me realize that we have no PGRaster documentation for MapServer, so I spent a few days documenting it:  https://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html#postgis-raster-pgraster   Thanks for the nudge!  #foss4g4ever -jeff

Comment: Thank you very much for the documentation. Concerning raster2pgsql: it is also possible to use rpostgis::pgWriteRast() within R to laod the raster. I was finally able to get this working.